oauth_host_starter.cc(125)] Error occurred when unregistering the existing host

\[0526/111943.530472:INFO:host_starter_base.cc(74)\]
Found existing host: `dc21e49a-xxxx-4631-8f2b-xxxxxxxxxxx`.
This instance will be deleted from the Directory before starting the new host instance.
\[0526/111946.496145:ERROR:oauth_host_starter.cc(125)\] Error occurred when unregistering the existing host.
\[0526/111946.622110:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(98)\] Killing process 773

When I set up my Ubuntu machine by using SSH into Google remote desktop, I faced the error above.
I want to set up my Ubuntu machine for remote access, Can you please tell me how can I solve it?
